# Check create duplicate for soft delete

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I had a database table named country. Each country has name and removed column. When user create a new country with name, a new row with name together with removed default 0 will be created. I had created unique index for name and removed columns.

What I want right now is able to create new row with name and removed 0 uniquely and also update with replace into where removed 1 or update the existing row where removed 0.

```
INSERT INTO country (name, removed) VALUES ('United State',0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name), removed = 1
SELECT name FROM country WHERE removed = 1
```

**Condition**

```
// If name doesn't exists in db, create new row with new name and removed 0
// If name exists in db, check for removed 1 for existing name:
            // If found, replace the new one with that removed 1 with removed 0
       // else replace the new one with that removed 0 (Works like upsert)
```

Comment: @Strawberry Doesn't really matter. Thanks you for mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have `UNIQUE(name, removed)`.  But that means that you can have 2 rows for each country??  Perhaps you want only `PRIMARY KEY(name)`.  This would allow IODKU (aka Upsert) based just on `name`.